# How to take path from batch in LyX2.3.2?

Tags: pdftex, windows, input, shell-escape

I'm using LyX in Windows 10 and searching to display the path where the file.tex is placed, this file is supposed to be placed in different places and used from different users.
I try to explain what I'm searching to do:
I have this *file.tex* where i want to put the complete path of where it's placed, for example *C:\users\name\latex file\file.tex*.
So I tried placing in "LaTeX Preamble":

```
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\immediate\write18{batch 'dir' > temp.tex}
```

To make possible the use of external programs I have put `--shell-escape` going on:

```
Tools->Preferences..->File Handling->Converts
```

And in "*LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)*" writing in *Converter* `pdflatex --shell-escape $$i`.
How you can see I'm using a temp file where put the output of the batch's command.
So I expect, after the launch of *file.tex*, to see in the *temp.tex* this:

*C:\users\name\latex file\file.tex*

I know that LaTeX don't like characters like '\' so I wrote a script.bat to replace '\' with '-' (I know it dont look really nice to see):

`Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-Content temp.tex -ReadCount 0) -replace [regex]::Escape('\'),'-' | Set-Content temp.tex"`

I tried to execute this file from LaTeX writing:

```
\immediate\write18{batch script.bat}
```

or:

```
\execute{.\script.bat}
```

After that in my *temp.tex* I expect something like:

*C:-users-name-latex file-file.tex*

To diplay it on the pdf of file.tex i put in a box with TEX-code(CTRL+L):

```
\input{temp.tex}
```

This solution doesnt work.
I readed a lot of other questions here in stackexchange and other forums but no one work...
Surely there is something that I'm making wrong but I dont know what.
I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: You could try to currfile package (needs the --recorder option to get the folder), but imho lyx copies the files to a temp folder before compiling so you would never get the "right" folder. Beside this: try at first if you can output and input a simple text and worry about backslashes and batch files later.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your answer. I tried with currfile package setting "_Latex(pdflatex)->PDF(pdflatex)_" converter in `pdflatex -recorder $$i`.
Then I wrote in _Latex Preamble_:
`\usepackage{currfile-abspath}
\usepackage{filehook}
\getmainfile
\getabspath{\themainfile}
\let\mainabsdir\theabsdir
\let\mainabspath\theabspath
`
And in the section {document}:
`\mainabspath`
Finally I saw something like what I want:
_C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.ITSNrKhFyQvx/lyx_tmpbuf0/file.tex_
How can i have the "right" folder? There is a solution?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Well don't use lyx if you want the folder of your document.